# Cúal es la mejor práctica para agregar un HTML en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo dos formas de agregar HTML con Javascript en un caso especial. Ambas formas me trabajan bien. Pero tengo la duda cual de las dos es mejor práctica.

Una es esta, creado un elemento para agregárselo al product list

```
const productList = document.getElementById('product-list');
const element = document.createElement('div')
    element.innerHTML = `
            <div class = "card text-center mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <strong> Product Name</strong>: ${product.name}
                    <strong> Product Price</strong>: ${product.price}
                    <strong> Product Year</strong>: ${product.year}
                <div>
            </div>
        `;
   productList.appendChild(element);
```

Y la otra forma es directamente con innerHTML, sin creatElement

```
const productList = document.getElementById('product-list');
        productList.innerHTML = `
            <div class = "card text-center mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <strong> Product Name</strong>: ${product.name}
                    <strong> Product Price</strong>: ${product.price}
                    <strong> Product Year</strong>: ${product.year}
                <div>
            </div>
        `;
```

Reitero, ambas trabajan bien pero tengo la duda de cuál sería mejor práctica.

Comment: Idealmente, lo mejor sería evitar mezclar de este modo HTML y JavaScript. Podrías hacerlo todo en JavaScript o tener el HTML en un template y procesarlo en JavaScript.

Comment: Me interesa lo que acabas de escribir @AlvaroMontoro . No lo conozco. ¿tiene alguna documentación o tutorial sobre el tema? gracias

Answer (score 3):

Esta pregunta [tiene su equivalente en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode) y la respuesta sigue siendo válida después de 8 años:

Usar `element.appendChild` es mejor cuando quieres añadir un hijo sin borrar los elementos existentes, porque cuando usas innerHTML obligas al navegador a reconstruir todo el DOM implicado, así que hacer en un bucle algo como

```
for (...) {
  let nuevoHijo ='...';
  element.innerHTML+= nuevoHijo;
}
```

es mucho más costoso para el navegador que usar

```
for (...) {
  const hijo= document.createElement('div')
  hijo.innerHTML='...';
  element.appendChild(hijo);
}
```

En cambio, cuando quieres borrar los elementos existentes y reemplazarlos, lo correcto y más sencillo es asignar el texto con `innerHTML`.

Una tercera opción es el método [`element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), que es algo intermedio: inserta texto pero lo añade sin borrar los potenciales hermanos

Answer (score 1):

Ambas soluciones son prácticamente idénticas. **En tu caso concreto** es mejor la segunda porque no estás creando un div adicional.

Pero si pudieras crear todos los elementos via createElement, quizás fuera una opción algo mejor.

Aquí se discute el tema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml

De nuevo: en tu caso no aplica porque la solución 1 y 2 es la misma, solo que la segunda crea un div adicional y acaba usando innerHTML en este nuevo div.

Para ser una comparación real entre innerHTML vs createElement, todos los elementos se deberían crear via createElement/appendChild y no solamente el contenedor externo.

Comment: ¿cuáles son tus bases para usar ese porcentaje de aceveración?

Comment: 99.99% = prácticamente. Mejor así? @AlfredoPaz  :-)